# Insertar en dos tablas a la vez

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

tengo la tabla general

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tengo la tabla línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente tengo la tabla empresa_linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando inserte en la tabla general se pase el id_general del nuevo registro a la tabla empresa_linea y poner también en la misma tabla y el mismo registro el id_linea que ya obtengo del formulario

> Mi Controlador con los datos que quiero insertar como ejemplo

```
public function add_empresa_linea(){//aqui debo de insertar en dos tablas
  $data = array(
    'nombre' => $this->input->post('txt_nombre'),
    'id_servicio' => 1,  
  );

  $id_linea = $this->input->post('combo_linea');

  $insert = $this->reg_calls_model->add_empresa_linea($data);

  if ($insert) {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));  
  }
}
```

> Mi Modelo

```
function add_empresa_linea($data){
  try {   
    $result = $this->db->insert('general',$data);

    return $result;
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es abrir una transacción con BEGIN, hacer todos los INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE incluso los SELECT que te hagan falta, y una ves que consideres que todo esta bien haces COMMIT y listo, de esta forma tienes lo que necesitas. Tendrás que buscar el equivalente de esto en tu framework.

Comment: un ejemplo aunque no sea en el framework

Comment: Hola Javier, lo puse como respuesta, espero que te ayude, si necesitas más información de MySQL y del SQL, no dudes en preguntar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es abrir una transacción con **BEGIN**, hacer todos los **INSERT**, **UPDATE**, **DELETE** incluso los **SELECT** que te hagan falta, y una ves que consideres que todo esta bien haces **COMMIT** y listo, de esta forma tienes lo que necesitas. Tendrás que buscar el equivalente de esto en tu framework, mientras te dejo un ejemplo en SQL:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO general (nombre, ...) VALUES ("prueba", ...);
INSERT INTO linea (numero, ...) VALUES ("55512345", ...);
SELECT id INTO @id_general FROM general WHERE nombre = "prueba";
SELECT id INTO @id_linea FROM linea WHERE numero = "55512345";
INSERT INTO empresa_linea (id_general, id_linea) VALUES (@id_general, @id_linea);
COMMIT;
```

Aclaro que los tres puntos (...) es para indicar el resto de columnas & valores que hay que completar, esto es un ejemplo.